# PHP - MySQL trying to set value="0" - it's NULL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just trying to set some value = "0", but it's automatically convert into NULL.

```
$result_checkups = mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1, COL2) VALUES (".(!empty($COL1) ? "'$COL1'" : "NULL").", ".(!empty($COL2) ? "'$COL2'" : "NULL").") or die(mysql_error());
```

It's my code - it look so strange, becouse I need to set NULL, when someone trying to set empty string ("").
But now, when `COL2="0"`, then it's `NULL` behind MySQL (to clear, when `COL2="1"`, it's "1" behind MySQL).
Where is problem?

MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `TABLE1` (
  `COL1` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  `COL2` TINYINT(1) NULL);
```

Comment: can you give us your table structure?

Comment: That's not even valid PHP and thus can't have the symptoms described. Try again.

Answer (score 6):

Because of

```
php -r 'echo empty(0);'
1
php -r 'echo empty("0");'
1
```

`0` is empty. Try to change your statement to:

```
$result_checkups = mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1, COL2) VALUES (".(($COL1==='') ?  "NULL" : "'$COL1'").", ".(($COL2==='') ? "NULL" : "'$COL2'").")") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Clean up your data with escape function to prevent [*sql-injection*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php);
2. Predefine data BEFORE insertion into query - it is cleaner and more readable.
3. Read [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) function documentation:

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> "" (an empty string)
>
> 0 (0 as an integer)
>
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
>
> "0" (0 as a string)
>
> NULL
>
> FALSE
>
> array() (an empty array)
>
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

So `"0"` is considered empty. I suggest you to use [`strlen()`](http://php.net/strlen) instead.

Try this:

```
$COL1 = mysql_real_escape_string($COL1);
$COL2 = mysql_real_escape_string($COL2);

$COL1 = strlen($COL1) ? $COL1 : 'NULL';
$COL2 = strlen($COL2) ? $COL2 : 'NULL';

$sql  = "INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1, COL2) VALUES ({$COL1}, {$COL2})";

$result_checkups = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

**P.S.:** MySQL extension is deprecated. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. Follow this [*link*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).